# Sequence of Ratios

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a positive real sequence and define $$r_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},\quad n\ge 0$$ Suppose that we know the formal power series of $a_n$, i.e. we know the following: $$A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$$ Then, is there any method by which we can find the formal power series of $r_n$, i.e. can we find the following as a function of $A(x)$, without explicitly putting values for $r_n$? $$R(x):=\sum_{n\ge 0}r_nx^n$$ At least, can we find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}r_n$(if it exists) in terms of $A(x)$? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean with means that do not "acces" the individual coefficients and combine the results, but rather with e.g. differential operators. That sounds difficult because we need an operator that fails for any series that has a zero coefficient *anywhere*

Comment: Yes, @HagenvonEitzen, I mean without explicitly putting values of $r_n$.